Why FCM token is no more received by the "didReceiveRegistrationToken" delegate
Here is our app situation:

We have one iOS app (same bundle ID) that can connect to either a North American (NAM) Firebase project or an European (EU) one that is selected based on phone's region.
Before November 15th everything was working.
Then we released the new iOS version or our app.
Since that release, the app connecting to the EU’s Firebase project no more receives a registration token when starting the application. We are using the "Messaging.messaging().delegate = self" and expect the "func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?)" delegate to be called.
I tried the quickstart project for messaging.

I created 2x app in Firebase and get the plist files. for the 2 different projects and using the same bundle id.
When connecting to the NAM cloud, I do receive the FCM token. If I connect to the EU project, I don’t get the token.
If I use a different bundle id for each project, then the apps always receive the FCM token.



Now, the question is this:
-> From now on, can we have the same app with the same bundle id used in 2 different Firebase clouds?
Thanks in advance
UPDATE 2024-12-10
I would like to add that today, I found out that the iPad Pro M1 does not have the token not received issue like a regular iPad or iPhone 13 Pro do.
Not sure how it can help, but wanted to share with you.

May be problem with APNS certificate in EU cloud?

@Cy-4AH, this is what I thought in the beginning, I did repush the certificate without fixing the issue. Also, during my validation with quickstart project, I noticed that I don't need to have an APN certificate to get the FCM token. So, does not seem to be related. I really think the certificate is only needed to receive push notification. I want to fix the first one before going further.
